# change order of add_action hooks for jquery to be loaded first

Tags: jquery, actions, order

[a slider plugin](http://themes.themepunch.com/?theme=revolution_wp) puts its javascript “right before the closing body-tag” using an add_action() hook like this:

```
protected static function addAction($action,$eventFunction){
    add_action( $action, array(self::$t, $eventFunction) );         
}
```

-

```
UniteBaseClassRev::addAction('wp_footer', 'putJavascript');
```

-

```
public function putJavascript(){
    $urlPlugin = UniteBaseClassRev::$url_plugin."rs-plugin/";
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo $urlPlugin?>js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js?rev=<?php echo GlobalsRevSlider::SLIDER_REVISION; ?>'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo $urlPlugin?>js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?rev=<?php echo  GlobalsRevSlider::SLIDER_REVISION; ?>'></script>
    <?php
}
```

[the theme I use](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress) also uses add_action() to unregister the wordpress jquery and use its own:

```
function FoundationPress_scripts() {
// deregister the jquery version bundled with wordpress
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
// enqueue modernizr, jquery and foundation
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr/modernizr.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'FoundationPress_scripts' );
```

now what happens is that the slider scripts are loaded before the jquery is loaded and therefore do not work:

[image: devtools]

so my question is how I can change the order of the add_action() hooks to be fired. any other solution to solve this is fine.

Comment: There's the "Dependency API" for that. Stuff like `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`. Take a look at [tag:wp-enqueue-script] for examples.

Comment: Themes should **never** deregister core-bundled jQuery. I recommend using a different Theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real answer here, is to have the plugin author load scripts properly using wp_enqueue_script().

Or, you could change the theme enqueue code to output jquery to the header by changing to this (not great for performance reasons, but relatively simple):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', false );
```

Or, you could rewrite the plugin code so that it uses the enqueue process.